# Node errorno ECONNREFUSED gmail stopped working

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have the following code on a website and it stopped sending e-mails, and when i try to debug, the shown error is the one below. I already enabled less secure apps to access the Gmail, but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

**address: "172.217.193.109"

code: "ESOCKET"

command: "CONN"

errno: "ECONNREFUSED"

port: 465

syscall: "connect"**

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.body);

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'example1@mail.com',
      pass: 'password'
    }
  });

  transporter.sendMail({
    to: 'example2@mail.com',
    replyTo: req.body.email,
    from: 'Example <example1@mail.com>',
    subject: 'Mensagem do site - '+req.body.name,
    html: '<b>Nome: </b> '+req.body.name+'<br />'+
          '<b>Telefone: </b>'+(req.body.phone || 'nao informado')+'<br />'+
          '<b>E-mail: </b>'+req.body.email+'<br /><br />'+
          '<b>Assunto: </b>'+req.body.subject+'<br />'+
          '<b>Mensagem: </b>'+req.body.message+'<br />'
  }).then(function(result){
    console.log("Deu certo?", result);
    res.send('OK');
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Deu ruim", error);
    res.send(error);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Bom día Mariana, this is probably because Google doesn't allow use of their smtp server from anywhere outside of the context they decide is allowed. If they do allow to send a couple of emails this way, you may have exceeded the daily/hourly limit they have. Try using Mailtrap.io as transport in nodemailer, it is awesome for testing and works perfectly well.

Comment: @mariana-caramico Have a look at : https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

Comment: @anatolhiman thank you so much for your reply! do you think I could use another e-mail, like hotmail or outlook, or any other one that is unlimited? bom dia!

Comment: I think all regular email services are blocked for requests of this type because otherwise anybody could abuse their servers sending massive amounts of spam from a local application. Once you are done testing with Mailtrap you could use a commercial solution like Sendgrid or Amazon Simple Email Service (very good service, and inexpensive) for a production app.

Comment: @anatolhiman do you think if I put a reCAPTCHA it would solve my problem?

Comment: No, Gmail/Google would not see that as any different (although it would stop potential spammers). This has to do with basic server sercurity policy and economic policy, they don't want to let whoever use resources (servers cost money to run) on their system that they can't benefit from in some way. It was easier to use Google's smtps earlier, but now I think it's very hard unless it is for using a custom email address in your free Gmail account (which is something else again).

Comment: @anatolhiman I tried using mailtrap.io, but the same error is shown :( the only differences are in the address and port: address: "54.158.84.126", port: 2525

Comment: Nodemailer needs a different port in your code, did you use 2525? Also, try without secure: true. Hard to send securely from your local computer set it to true when you send from a web server. You'll find the Mailtrap config for Nodemailer in your Mailtrap account once you have created your fist mailbox. See this image: https://imgur.com/a/wEzyWxt